# Not in and In together or exist or not exist for finding renewed orders

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

The query is this to find renewed orders

A renewal is any school that PAID (i.e. total_line_price >0) for an order in the previous school year , but that same school has purchased (paid for – total line price>0) another order.

next year '08-01-2016 00:00:00' and '07-31-2017 00:00:00' -2016

current year '08-01-2015 00:00:00' and '07-31-2016 00:00:00' -2015

previous year '08-01-2014 00:00:00' and '07-31-2015 00:00:00' - 2014

Below is query that i have written and its not right. Need some help

```
select 
(school_ucn 
from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order 
where school_ucn not in ((select school_ucn
                          from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order 
                          where (((start_date between  '08-01-2014 00:00:00' and '07-31-2015 00:00:00') 
                          and (total_line_price >0) ))

                          and in 
                          (select school_ucn
                          from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order
                          where ((start_date between '08-01-2015 00:00:00' and '07-31-2016 00:00:00') and ( total_line_price >0))
                          )))
```

Comment: I suggest showing what's not working in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: It is giving me syntactical error ... Just give me the logic to use NOT In and  IN in the same query ...

Comment: An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select school_ucn 
from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order 
where school_ucn not in ((select school_ucn
                          from sto...

ERROR: function storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order(boolean) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Execution time: 0.04s
1 statement failed.

Comment: Once you have something in sqlfiddle.com you can add it to your question.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (They handle date/time in different ways, both in a non-ANSI SQL manner...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `and in` inside your query. It should be `and school_ucn in`.

Always format your query properly to analyse easily.

```
select school_ucn 
  from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order 
 where school_ucn not in (
                          select school_ucn
                          from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order 
                          where  start_date between  '08-01-2014 00:00:00' and '07-31-2015 00:00:00' 
                          and    total_line_price >0)
   and school_ucn in (select school_ucn 
                        from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order
                       where start_date between '08-01-2015 00:00:00' and '07-31-2016 00:00:00' 
                         and total_line_price >0)
```

Using Not Exists, you can rewrite your query as follows.

```
select school_ucn 
  from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order as a
 where start_date between '08-01-2015 00:00:00' and '07-31-2016 00:00:00' 
   and total_line_price >0
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from storiacloud_staging.schl_royl_vw_edw_oms_order as b 
                    where b. school_ucn = a. school_ucn
                      and start_date between  '08-01-2014 00:00:00' and '07-31-2015 00:00:00’
                      and total_line_price >0)
```

Comment: Thanks . Much appreciated. I will try and format it better next time

Comment: @harshilbhatt Pls accept it as answer if it had helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks